# SQL Compact Edition 4.0 CTP1 needs Visual C++ 2008 Runtime Libraries SP1

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, sql-server-ce

SQL Compact Edition 4.0 CTP1 needs Visual C++ 2008 Runtime Libraries SP1 and if SQL CE is deployed privately in the application’s BIN folder the following have to be present on the machine for it to function properly:

a.      Installing the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 also installs the Visual C++ 2008 Runtime Libraries SP1.

b.      Or install the Visual C++ 2008 Runtime Libraries SP1 redist.

Installing .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0 or 4.0 does not install the Visual C++ 2008 Runtime Libraries SP1.

**Problem:** My host doesn't have 3.5 SP1 installed. Does anyone know of a way around this, such as bin deploy the C++ 2008 runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Ask your host to install NetFX 3.5 SP1
2: Ask your host to install VC++ 2008 Redist
3: Maybe this? http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104529/Deploying-Visual-Cplusplus-Runtime-Files-as-Privat.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The final release seems to have officially handled this case.

From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx

> Note that the native DLLs of SQL
>   Server Compact need the Microsoft
>   Visual C++ 2008 Runtime Libraries (x86
>   and x64) SP1 to function properly. The
>   assemblies for the Visual C++ 2008
>   runtime are present in the Private
>   folder, and deploying all the DLLs and
>   folders in the Private folder deploys
>   all the files needed for Compact to
>   work properly.